# What is the meaning of rotation in $ct$-$x$ plane via an imaginary angle?

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, rotation, lorentz-symmetry, complex-numbers

A Lorentz boost along the $x$-direction (say) can be thought of as a rotation through an imaginary angle in the $(ct,x)$ plane. Is this purely an academic exercise or does it give any interesting physical insight?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/287301/2451

Comment: Yes. It is purely a mathematical exercise and doesn't lead to any enlightening insight into Lorentz boosts. Boosts are boosts. Rotations are rotations.

Answer (score 1):

All "purely mathematical exercises" in physics lead to physical insights, and it's *very* enlightening to think of boosts as skews (which are the "real" sort, as opposed to rotations, which have imaginary eigenvalues etc.). It helps you discover stuff like the Minkowski dot product and magnitude for yourself (because the Euclidean dot product is invariant under rotations, we want a dot product which is invariant under the general Lorentz transformation, including both t-x, t-y, t-z skews as well as x-y, x-z, y-z rotations.

Another thing is that treating the skews as rotations helps familiarise you a bit early with rotations in 4-dimensions (since there are ${}^4C_2=6$ rotations in 4 dimensions, you can't attach each to a single dimension like you can in 3), which is a useful skill in general relativity.