# The need for placeholder in tensor notation

Tags: tensor-calculus, notation

In many books of GR, e.g., Sean Carroll, Wald, empty-space placeholders are added on the tensor component, e.g., in Wald's book

> $$
> T = \sum^n_{\mu_1, \cdots, \nu_l =1} T^{\mu_1 \cdots \mu_k}_{\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \nu_1 \cdots \nu_l} \,\,\, \nu_{\mu_1} \otimes \cdots \otimes \nu^{\nu_l*}   \tag{2.3.3}
> $$

For mathematical literature, e.g., [Using tensor products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor#Using_tensor_products), no placeholder （e.g., the empty spaces in the subscript of component of $T$ in 2.3.3 above) is used.

Will this difference lead to any ambiguity? I guess
$$
T^1_{\,\,\,2} e_1 \otimes e^2 
$$
is not
$$
T^{\,\,\,1}_{2} e^2 \otimes e_1 .
$$
So, if one uses the full notation, component + basis, the basis will distinguish the difference and the placeholder is not needed. Is that because physicist's literature uses components more often, e.g., $T^1_{\,\,\,2}$, so it is necessary to add the placeholder?

Comment: By placeholder you mean slanted indices?

Comment: I mean empty spaces, like $\Lambda^{\mu}_{\,\,\,\,\,\, \nu}$ in the subscripts, than $\Lambda^{\mu}_{ \nu}$. From the wikipedia convention in op, Wald's 2.3.3 will be $ T^{\mu_1 \cdots \mu_k}_{\nu_1 \cdots \nu_l} $, I think.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the horizontal position of tensor indices may be important. Especially if there is a metric tensor to raise and lower indices (i.e. the vertical position of indices via the [musical isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_isomorphism)), ambiguities may otherwise occur. For a simple illuminating example, see e.g. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/567237/2451) Phys.SE post (although the Lorentz transformation is technically speaking not a tensor).